# PEP302 implemention details needed

Tags: python, python-import

I am attempting to use PEP302 based import hooks to catch the importing of modules so I can have some encrypted .py files that would get loaded at run time. I am following the template on python obfuscation at https://github.com/citrusbyte/python-obfuscation.

The basic idea is simple: intercept the import command using a Finder() function inserted into sys.meta_path that catches an import directive. The Finder checks if the module is one we want to handle ourselves and if so, returns a custom Loader object. Otherwise it ignores the import. The custom loader creates an entry in sys.modules and reads in the python module source and add it to the newly created module using exec as defined in the PEP302 documentation.

This works mostly fine, but I have one specific situation that I cannot figure out. Assume 3 files, main, foo, and bar. main sets up the import hook then imports foo, and bar. foo itself imports bar. So the situation is:

```
main:
  set_import_hook
  import foo
  import bar
foo:
  import bar
bar:
  <irrelevant>
```

I have debug statements in the Finder function set as the hook to see what it is being passed.

When I have unencrypted code (i.e., code that I do not process and add to sys.modules myself, the printouts show the following behavior:

```
Finder (foo)
Finder (bar) called from inside foo when foo itself is loaded
Finder (bar) called from main after returning from the import foo
```

When I process and load the foo and bar files myself, here is the behavior:

```
Finder (foo)
Finder (foo.bar) tries to load bar in the context of foo
Finder (bar) called from main after returning from import foo
```

This causes two versions of bar to exist in sys.modules. If you look at sys.modules.keys() in the two cases, in the first case it only shows foo and bar. In the second case it shows foo, foo.bar, and bar.

I don't understand this behavior. The process of creating the module is as described in the PEP 302 document. This is what I use:

```
    module = sys.modules.setdefault(name, imp.new_module(name))
    module.__file__ = filename
    module.__path__ = [os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(file.name))]
    module.__loader__ = self
    sys.modules[name] = module
    exec(src, module.__dict__)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of looking at various examples and documentation, I have a partial answer.

In the code above I noticed that I was not setting `module.__package__`. Somewhere in the import process, that resulted in an entry of `foo.__package__ = 'foo'` being set in the module definition. This resulted in foo being considered a package and any imports it made being considered imports relative to the package directory.

When running against imports where I was not doing the module setup, I saw that the `module.__package__` was set to None by the system. But setting `module.__package__ = None` in the code above did not work. Something reset it to foo.

The solution that worked was to set `module.__package__ = ''` (the null string). So the working piece of the code for adding the module is:

```
module = sys.modules.setdefault(name, imp.new_module(name))
module.__file__ = filename
module.__path__ = [os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(file.name))]
module.__loader__ = self
module.__package__ = ''
sys.modules[name] = module
exec(src, module.__dict__)
```

This is working now, and the modules foo and bar get imported only once. Behavior of the encrypted and nonencrypted modules looks similar.

I still do not understand where the `module.__package__` gets set if it is not explicitly set to `''`.